# unitPngFix doesn't show PNGs

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer-6, png

I am using WordPress. I want PNG backgrounds through CSS.
Now in themes folder in default theme I've placed UnitPNGFIX in JS folder. In same folder I've put clear.gif and also renamed path in JS  from

```
var clear="image/clear.gif";
```

to

```
var clear="clear.gif";
```

Now when I am observing it in IE6, it shows no PNGs.

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't need to fix the PNG images.

Comment: I don't know UnitPNGFix, but there are other similar tools that don't require a clear.gif file. Maybe you could try one of them instead?

Comment: @Spudley Let me know some perfectly working Examples for PNGS called in background through CSS

Answer (score 0):

By CSS you need to address the image at thie way:

background:url("../img/clear.gif") no-repeat;

if the image is in the js directory of your theme you can referred to it by the path "../js/clear.gif"

Comment: I think you have not gone through UnitPNGFix, this is not css thing.